# QueryDSL Q classes are generated in target folder but cannot be imported in other spring boot modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have multi module project (spring boot) and I configured QueryDSL in dao module it's working perfectly and it generated all Q classes.
But when I import this module in service module and I import a Q class in the IDE (Intellij) it does not show any error but when running mvn clean install I get an error that the class is unresolved.

```
Unresolved reference: QRole
```

Here is the code for pom (dao module) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
    <description>Module that have repositories and entities.</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database & JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kotlin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-kotlin-codegen</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                            <classifier>jpa</classifier>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                                <source>src/main/resources</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>target/generated-sources/kapt/test</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is:

1. Right-click the project folder
2. Select Maven
3. Select **Generate Sources And Update Folders**

Then, Intellij automatically imports generated sources to the project.